# Error while compiling gcc-2.7.2.3

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, x86-64

When I try to compile it, I get,

```
as: unrecognized option '-EL'
```

Any idea what kind of error is this and how it could be fixed?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the "-EL" option ?  Is that an option that you purposely invoked ? Or is it something that appeared by unknown magic that someone else decided should be on the assembler's list of options ?

Comment: No, it is already there.

Answer (score 2):

The `-EL` option means little endian target building. It has real sense only for multi-endian generic targets (PowerPC, ARM) and needn't be recognized on strict endian targets as e.g. x86. I think it's so removed from assembler and linker support on them.

For this gcc version you likely should use binutils of the same historic period, otherwise too many subtle inconsistencies could spoil your life. But this also needs many other software becoming ancient. Why don't you simply install some old (1995-1998) OS in a virtual machine? There are many alternatives as RedHat 4.x, FreeBSD 2.x, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's an unrecognized option to the assembler, probably gas. Checking the [docs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/as/Invoking.html#Invoking), I don't see such option listed. Checking the [docs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) for `ld` tho, `-EL` is an option to the linker. Prefixing it with `-Wl,` could help. Try `-Wl, -EL`.